# Force uploaded image to keep its proportion

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I dispaly image in an image tag

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="50" />
```

I user uploads image size 100x100 I want it to be displayed like the tag above is

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
```

How to achieve that?

ps

I am using php if it is server side issue at all.

Comment: So you want to keep the proportions of the image, and set either the width or height?

Comment: Not to set, just to stay proportional in the limit either width or height. If original picture is 100x10 and the tag is <img src="image.jpg" width="50" height="70" /> I need whole 50 pixels of width to be used and only 10 pixels of 70 available for height. It will be a lot of empty space but image will keep it shape. I hope I made the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getimagesize()` to get the image size.  Then do this to shrink-to-fit, but maintaining the aspect ratio:

```
if ($width > $height)
{
    $ratio = (float)100 / $width;
}
else
{
    $ratio = (float)100 / $height;
}

$width  = (int)round($width  * $ratio);
$height = (int)round($height * $ratio);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will fit any image to maxWidth x maxHeight box, keeping aspect ratio and padding with white background.

```
$img = new Imagick('orig.jpg');
$maxWidth = 100;
$maxHeight = 50;

$geom = $img->getImageGeometry();
$fitWidth = (($maxWidth/$geom['width'])<($maxHeight/$geom['height']))?true:false;
if($fitWidth){
    $img->thumbnailImage($maxWidth,0,false);
}else{
    $img->thumbnailImage(0,$maxHeight,false);
}

$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newImage($maxWidth,$maxHeight,'white','jpg');

$geom = $img->getImageGeometry();
$x = ($maxWidth-$geom['width'])/2;
$y = ($maxHeight-$geom['height'])/2;
$canvas->compositeImage($img,imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,$x,$y);

$canvas->writeImage('thumb.jpg');
```